# using Actions for html select box in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, html-select

i am trying to select an item from a html select box using selenium phantomjs driver `org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions` along with it i am also taking a screen shot to see whether its moves the mouse cursor to the specified item in the select box so far tried below code with no success: (i have placed comment on each block of actions below)

```
lblstatus.setText("Selecting Gender...");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//select[@name='gender']")));

//for moving mouse pointer on select box
mouse.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='gender']"))).perform();

//for performing click on select box, assuming here the selectbox will show its dropdown items
mouse.click(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='gender']"))).perform();

//for moving mouse pointer on MALE option (but not yet clicked or selected)
mouse.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='gender']/option[@value='MALE']"))).perform();

//taking screen shot, assuming that currently mouse pointer is on MALE option
try {
       File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
       FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("selectbox.png"));
} catch (IOException ioe) {
       System.err.println(ioe.getMessage());
}
```

the above code works fine with no error, but when i open `selectbox.png` its not giving me what i am trying to get, i am expecting the screnshot similar to the below image:

[image]

so is it possible to achieve that? with `org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions` if yes, then how could i achieve that, important i want it with `Actions` cause my task is to achieve that using `Actions` class of `org.openqa.selenium.interactions` , my requirement is not the screen shot but using `org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions` to select an item from select box.

UPDATE:

i tried the same with `FirefoxDriver` and found that above code does exactly what i am looking for, but i am not able to see mouse pointer movement on the elements while it sending keys and selecting the right option from selectbox, so does it mean that its actually moving the mouse pointer but no one can see it, the FirefoxDriver opens the new firefox window before i was doing it with `phantomjs` so screenshots helps me to see the actual process that phantomjs is doing but in case of FirefoxDriver no screenshot is needed as i am able to see it live.

now my question is:

is it actually doing the mouse movement on the elements or not? or it is doing but i can't see it? please help.

Answer (score 0):

User gestures are "emulated", as said in `Actions.class`
In Selenium RC it was mostly with JS, in Selenium Webdriver - with a more internal browser mechanism, but it is clear that both "element" and "keyboard/mouse" actions have the same nature - see `DriverCommand` and have nothing to do with system mouse/keyboard.

You won't see the mouse pointer anyway when doing screenshot.

In the end it is unclear to me why one would use

```
mouse.moveToElement
mouse.click
mouse.moveToElement(option)
```

instead of `selectByVisibleText` on a real html select.

Comment: i am using the above steps, because i want to simulate real user behaviour and real user interaction while testing my web app, for ex: as a real user we first move mouse to the element and then we perform the click event to see the result, so i am too trying to simulate the same but using selenuim, but i found that didn't work for me.. and last option for me is to use `selectByVisibleText` so i do... and thanks for your answer.

Comment: @noobdeveloper99 If it is a HTML select, it will work anyway 100%, so performing click-move-click is not very consistent, selectByVisibleText is an idustrial standard of test automation in such case. On the contary, if you're going to select something from <div> element, you will have to hover-(maybe move)-click, yes.